# Basic Twitter Bootstrap grid glitch

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it me or does `col-xs-12` start very early when changing the window size? https://jsfiddle.net/t0o0capo/

For example, I want my divs on mobile to have background black but it's this colour at desktop. Why is this?

```js
/* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */
```

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

.col-lg-4 {
  background:red
}

.col-md-4 {
  background:green
}

.col-sm-4 {
  background:blue
}

.col-xs-12 {
  background:black;
}

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 thumb">
               <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            
            

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 thumb">
               <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            
            

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 thumb">
               <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
            
        <hr>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your css will always be applied as it is not wrapped in media queries.

I have updated your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjaart/gnwz0pdv/2/) to show a working example:

```
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

.col-xs-12 {
  background:black;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) 
{  
    .col-sm-4 {
        background:blue
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) 
{ 
   .col-md-4 {
       background:green
   }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) 
{ 
    .col-lg-4 {
        background:red
    }
}

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

You can find the standard bootstrap media query sizes [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)

> /* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
> /* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */
>
> /* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
> @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }
>
> /* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
> @media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }
>
> /* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
> @media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your CSS rule in a media query.  The `col-xs-12` class is always present, so your div will always get the styles.

Comment: Thanks Cody. Is there any existing standard media queries for Bootstrap 3 I should be using?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Bootstrap uses, to my knowledge, `min-width` 480, 768, 992 and 1200 pixels for media queries.

Answer (score 1):

It is happening since "col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 thumb" in your divs  and using same classes in your CSS (class col-xs-12 is always applied to your div and since it is pre-last class there - color of background is black). What do you want is Bootstrap media selectors:

```
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min)
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min)
@media (min-width: @screen-xs-min)
```

etc. Here is documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

Upd: added explanation why it is black.